# Проблема с задачей Android Gradle :app:mergeDebugResources (AAPT2 процесс неожиданно завершился)

Tags: android, gradle, кэширование

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error during compile '/home/twillight/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bbc219d6e1215389ee1dfb92d4bf9e83/jetified-play-services-base-17.0.0/res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error during compile '/home/twillight/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bbc219d6e1215389ee1dfb92d4bf9e83/jetified-play-services-base-17.0.0/res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error during compile '/home/twillight/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bbc219d6e1215389ee1dfb92d4bf9e83/jetified-play-services-base-17.0.0/res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error during compile '/home/twillight/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/bbc219d6e1215389ee1dfb92d4bf9e83/jetified-play-services-base-17.0.0/res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

У меня уже есть давно созданный проект, который я поддерживаю и обновляю.

Все было хорошо до сегодняйшего дня, пока не произошла ошибка со сборкой проекта

Версия Gradle Plugin: 4.1.1, Gradle: 6.5

Я перепробовал следующие варианты решения:

1. Сброс кэша и перезапуск Android Studio
2. Обновление версии gradle и плагина, а также понижение
3. Удалял вручную директорию gradle, и заново переустанавливал

В интернете нашел похожие проблемы, но решения не помогли
С такой же версией gradle и плагином хорошо работает другое приложение

Comment: У меня то же самое при сборке релиза. Пришлось вернуть AGP версии 4.0.2

Comment: А что за AGP? Не подскажите? Другие проекты хорошо собираются, проблема только в моем.

Comment: **A**ndroid **G**radle **P**lugin - тот что у вас 4.1.1.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за вашу помощь, вы очень помогли, я понизил версию и ошибка стала сразу понятна. Проблема была в том, что я использовал Preference пакет из androidx, который не был подключен в приложение, поэтому некоторые параметры отсутствовали. Теперь все хорошо работает